# Android database taking so much time

Tags: android, database

I want to store 3000 rows in a database in my Android App. It is taking so much time. Is there any solution to reduce the time duration?

UPDATE:

```
public long insertContac1(String country, String city, String category)
{ 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub ContentValues
    initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_COUNTRY, country);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CITY, city);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, initialValues);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us, how you are string those records in the DB.

Comment: do you store 3000 row in android simulator with using sqlite?

Comment: public long insertContac1(String country, String city, String category) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    
    initialValues.put(KEY_COUNTRY, country);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CITY, city);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
   
    
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, initialValues);
 
}

Comment: i use this insert query and then using for loop i m doing it 3000 time .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to wrap all in a single transaction:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try{        
    // your 3000 insert loop here 
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTranscation();
}
```

Comment: i am uses this..but taking time...is there any other meathod?

Comment: @Nirav it will take some time anyway.. I suggest to compare the time difference btw using transaction and not using transaction.

Comment: In my application inittially i store data in databse from xml which takes abt 2 minute....which is very big time....so i need to decrease it.....bcoz other wise no one wait for 2 minute in starting of any app...

Comment: @Nirav if even with a transaction it takes too long, you could do inserts in a separate thread. but this would require more coordination with the code which reads this data from the database

Comment: It actually works! I'm doing something similar and this method DID speed up my insertions, I just would like to know why? I did take a look at the documentation  (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setTransactionSuccessful()) but I didn't quite get it, is it buffering my transactions in some way?